# SOCKS proxy environment variable ignored by command line applications

Tags: terminal, network, catalina, proxy, zsh

I have a SOCKS proxy that is accessible at `192.168.0.17:1080` in my local network. I redirected my internet traffic to it in my Wifi System Preferences. This works fine, GUI applications use it. However I'm not able to use the proxy inside the terminal through environment variables. Only setting it explicitly works.

In other words, **this works**

```bsh
curl --socks5-hostname 192.168.0.17:1080 https://apple.stackexchange.com
```

But this **doesn't work**

```bsh
# exports are also in ~/.zshrc
export HTTP_PROXY="socks5://192.168.0.17:1080"
export http_proxy="socks5://192.168.0.17:1080"
export HTTPS_PROXY="socks5://192.168.0.17:1080"
export https_proxy="socks5://192.168.0.17:1080"
export ALL_PROXY="socks5://192.168.0.17:1080"

curl https://apple.stackexchange.com
```

This is not just the case for `curl` but also other applications such as `git`.

Comment: Looks like you're not using the documented "socks5h://" from the man page, specified as the equivalent to --socks5-hostname.  Any particular reason?

Comment: It works with "socks5h://", at least for some applications. You can write an answer if you'd like. What's the difference between h and non-h actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're passing --sox5-hostname, then the equivalent in environment variables is "socks5h://", per the man page for curl(1):

```
PROXY PROTOCOL PREFIXES
       Since curl version 7.21.7, the proxy string may be specified with a  protocol://  prefix  to  specify
       alternative proxy protocols.

       If  no  protocol is specified in the proxy string or if the string doesn't match a supported one, the
       proxy will be treated as an HTTP proxy.

       The supported proxy protocol prefixes are as follows:

       socks4://
              Makes it the equivalent of --socks4

       socks4a://
              Makes it the equivalent of --socks4a

       socks5://
              Makes it the equivalent of --socks5

       socks5h://
              Makes it the equivalent of --socks5-hostname
```